# Google Drive API Python Service Account Example

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

Is it possible to authenticate against the Google Drive API using a Google Service Account, rather than an OAuth flow ?

The Python examples for Google Drive use OAuth -  [Google drive Python Quick start](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

However I can't find any Service Account examples.

The majority of the other Google APIs I use (Translate, Cloud Vision) *do* use Service Account however, so I'd like to deprecate my Google Drive OAuth code for consistency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best service account python example that i know of is the one for [Google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py)

It should be something like this.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '<REPLACE_WITH_JSON_FILE>'
VIEW_ID = '<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>'


def initialize_drive():
  """Initializes an service object.

  Returns:
    An authorized service object.
  """
  creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

  return service
```

Once you have the drive service you should be able to use the rest of the code you have from the other tutorial.  Its just the auth method that is diffrent.

Just remember to create service account credentials and not Oauth credentials.

Comment: Follow - on question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64677744/gdrive-export-using-service-account-creds-fails-with-404

Answer (score 3):

You can use Credentials oauth2 object using the following,

```
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

service_account_info = json.load(open('service_account.json'))
creds=Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    service_account_info, scopes=SCOPES)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```