# Shared Google drive suddenly returning 404 with service account

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a Google Cloud Platform service account with domain-wide delegation enabled and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope.

Until recently the server using this account has not had any problems connecting to three different drives, creating folders underneath them, or returning a folder's contents. The server has used this account since early/mid 2020 and these API calls have been working correctly for a long time.

Now, the server is getting 404s when trying to create folders underneath a drive or list a directory's contents under the drive. The drive and those folders definitely exist - I can access them on the Google Drive web page. That leads me to believe this is a permissions issue but I have not found anything on my search. Nothing has changed regarding the service account or our server that I know of.

This is the code for creating a folder underneath a drive that now returns a 404 and tells me the drive does not exist (I am using `google-api-python-client` for this. I have [filed an issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/1186#issuecomment-823583024) with them but I do not believe it is an issue with the library):

```py
file_metadata = {
    'name':  name,
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    'parents': [drive_id]
}

file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id', supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
```

And here is the error returned:

```json
{
  "domain": "global",
  "location": "fileId",
  "locationType": "parameter",
  "message": "File not found: <drive_id>",
  "reason": "notFound"
}
```

Additionally, this is only an issue for two of the three drives this server connects to. One still works properly so I have no idea what has changed to cause this issue with two of the three drives. I think this has only started in the past few weeks because my users only notified me in the past few weeks, and the metrics page doesn't show any issues before the 12th (but I can only see the past 30 days):

[Metrics page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJmtZ.png)

Google's documentation on this is not helpful for fixing the issue: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_404_error_file_not_found_fileid

Can anyone help me figure this out or point me in the correct direction?

In case it helps, here is what our credentials for using the service account on the server looks like:

```json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "<project_id>",
  "private_key_id": "<private_key_id>",
  "private_key": "<private_key>",
  "client_email": "<service_account_client_email>",
  "client_id": "<service_account_client_id>",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/<url_encoded_service_account_email>"
}
```

Comment: Please include the full error message.   Note parents is not a drive id parents is a folder id.

Comment: Moreover, can you confirm you are passing the correct id? @Squirrel623

Comment: Who ever closed voted this as networking needs to look up what a service account authentication is with Google oauth.

Comment: @DaImTo sorry, I should have included the error from the start. I have edited the original post with the error.

Comment: @ale13 Yes I have confirmed that the ID of the drive I am passing in the example is the same ID I see when viewing the shared drive at `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/<drive_id>`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to waste everyone's time - the issue seems to have been that the service account was removed from the drive's members by a user who did not know what they were doing. I was not the developer to set this up and I am inexperienced with the Google Drive API so I did not know to check the members of the drive for the service account.

For others who might have the same issue:

Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64679709/5404586) to see if the service account is still a member and add it if needed.

You can check https://admin.google.com/ac/reporting/audit/drive and filter on `Event name: Shared Drive Membership Change` to see who removed the service account.